# How to get userId from database without Auth::()?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get current userId from database without Auth::() and I don't want to get it from route like `'/xxx/{id}'`

Is there any other way to get the userId without Auth::()?

eg. `$userId = User::where('id', $id)->pluck('id');`

Here is my auth::controller declaration :

```
public function getLogout(Request $request)
    {

        $redis = \Redis::connection();
        $user = $request->user();

    if ($user) {
         $userID = $user->id;
      }
 //       $userId = User::where('id', $id)->pluck('id'); 
        dd($userID);
 //       $userId=Auth::user()->id;
        $userSessions = $redis->smembers('users:sessions:' . $userId);
        $currentSession = Session::getId();
        foreach ($userSessions as $sessionId) {
             if ($currentSession == $sessionId) {
          continue; 

                }
                 $redis->srem('users:sessions:' . $userId, $sessionId);
                $redis->del('laravel:' . $sessionId);

            }
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('main');
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried `$userId = User::where('id', $id)->pluck('id');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the **[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)**:

> Alternatively, once a user is authenticated, you may access the
>   authenticated user via an `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance. Remember,
>   type-hinted classes will automatically be injected into your
>   controller methods:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the user's profile.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()) {
            // $request->user() returns an instance of the authenticated user...
        }
    }
}
```

So, it would be something like this to get the ID:

```
$user = $request->user();

if ($user) {
    $userID = $user->id;
}
```

Comment: I got the error like this : `Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::getLogout()`

As I have already said I don't want to get the `{id}` from Routes

Comment: Can you show us `AuthController::getLogout()` declaration?

Comment: You are injecting the `Request $request` instance to the controller method, so you don't need the `id` param anymore. Make sure it's gone from the method declaration, as well as the `getLogout()` route.